# WkHTMLtoPDF Unicode Issue

Tags: unicode, wkhtmltopdf, laravel-snappy, knp-snappy

I've already read several similar StackOverflow posts and none of them were able to resolve my issue.

### The Issue

I have a PDF that's being generated by WkHTMLtoPDF which contains a unicode `RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK` (U+2019, or `’`) character. Rendered in a browser, the output looks like the following:

[image: working image - in a browser]

When I run this through WkHTMLtoPDF, I get the following:

[image: failed image - in wkhtmltopdf]

### The Code

I'm using the following for my CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: localGeorgia;
    src: url("file:///usr/share/fonts/truetype/georgia/GEORGIA.TTF");
}

body {
    overflow: visible !important;
    font-family: localGeorgia, Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

I have also copied the Georgia font from my local computer to the server (there are several files in the `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/georgia/` directory) and I have run `fc-cache -fv` to clear the font cache and run `fc-list` to verify that `Georgia` was properly installed. The `localGeorgia` font family was added as a formality because I still wasn't getting a working display.

I've verified both via the online docs and my operating system's character map that the Georgia font does support the `RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK` (see below) although I don't know how to prove definitively that this glyph is in the TrueType file (I'm not familiar with opening or parsing TrueType files)

[image: Windows character map for Georgia font]

At this point it's unclear to me why WkHTMLtoPDF is displaying this mess of characters instead of the proper unicode glyph

### Additional details (environment and such)

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04

Laravel version 5.3

I'm using Laravel-Snappy version 0.3.3 (which is using KNP-Snappy version 0.4.3)

My config for Snappy is pretty straight-forward:

```
<?php
return array(
    'pdf' => array(
        'enabled' => true,
        'binary'  => base_path('vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64'),
        'timeout' => false,
        'options' => array(),
        'env'     => array(),
    ),
    'image' => array(
        'enabled' => false,
        'binary'  => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage',
        'timeout' => false,
        'options' => array(),
        'env'     => array(),
    ),
);
```

The installed wkhtmltopdf version is 0.12.3 (with patched qt)

To generate the PDF I'm calling `->render()` on the View, passing this to `PDF::loadHTML`, then calling `->inline()` on the result and returning a response. Here's a minimal example of how I'm generating the PDF:

```
$property = Property::find(1);
$view = View::make("pdf.flier")->with(["property" => $property]);
$pdf = PDF::loadHTML($view->render())->inline();
return response($pdf)->header("application/pdf")->header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=flier.pdf");
```

The HTML is incredibly simple:

```
<html>
<head>
    <base href="{{ url("/") }}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/flier.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <img src="{{ $property->image }}" />
    <h1>{{ $property->title }}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS gives the `h1` an absolute position over top of the image

Answer (score 34, accepted):

After a couple of days, I've finally figured this out

The issue does ***not*** lie with the font. If it did, I would see a glyph fail to load (e.g. - a box or a question mark would appear in place of the unicode character)

Instead what I'm seeing is ***several*** incorrect glyphs appear in place of the desired unicode character. This indicates an **encoding** issue, not a **font** issue. WkHTMLtoPDF is interpreting the 3-byte unicode character as 3 individual 1-byte ASCII characters

The problem is that my browser has a default encoding of UTF-8, but WkHTMLtoPDF does not (at least not in version 0.12.3). The fix was simple: update my config file

```
<?php
return array(
    'pdf' => array(
        'enabled' => true,
        'binary'  => base_path('vendor/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64'),
        'timeout' => false,
        'options' => array(
            'encoding' => 'utf-8'
        ),
        'env'     => array(),
    ),
    'image' => array(
        'enabled' => false,
        'binary'  => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltoimage',
        'timeout' => false,
        'options' => array(
            'encoding' => 'utf-8'
        ),
        'env'     => array(),
    ),
);
```

**Note:** In my research I found some examples of people claiming the "--encoding" option did not work for them, however adding a meta charset tag to the HTML did:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: That's what I found too! Adding: `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><meta charset="UTF-8" />` fixed the issue for me

Comment: that is a nice RCA. Upvoted !

Comment: Can confirm this works. German Umlaute and other special Characters like the currency sign € were displayed correctly in the generated pdf after adding `<meta charset="utf-8">` to my template, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

On my end, I fixed that issue by loading appropriate fonts as shown in the screenshot:

[image]